# numpy resize n-dimensional array with padding

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays, `a` and `b`.

`a` has shape `(1, 2, 3, 4)`

`b` has shape `(4, 3, 2, 1)`

I would like to make them both `(4, 3, 3, 4)` with the new positions filled with 0's.

I can do:

```
new_shape = (4, 3, 3, 4)

a = np.resize(a, new_shape)
b = np.resize(b, new_shape)
```

..but this repeats the elements of each to form the new elements, which does not work for me.

Instead I thought I could do:

```
a = a.resize(new_shape)
b = b.resize(new_shape)
```

..which according to the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html) pads with 0's.

But it doesn't work for multi-dimensional arrays, raising error:

> ValueError: resize only works on single-segment arrays

So is there a different way to achieve this? ie. same as np.resize but with 0-padding?

*NB: I am only looking for pure-numpy solutions.*

**EDIT: I'm using numpy version 1.20.2**

**EDIT: I just found out that is works for numbers, but not for objects, I forgot to mention that it is an array of objects not numbers.**

Comment: `a.resize(4,3,3,4, refcheck=False)`? See the different documentations [numpy.ndarray.resize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html#numpy.ndarray.resize) and [numpy.resize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html)

Comment: @not_speshal no produces same error

Comment: Definitely works for me (numpy v1.20.2). Check your numpy version.

Comment: @not_speshal 1.20.2, definitely does not work for me.

Comment: @MustafaAydın Not on my pc, just upgraded, I have no idea why

Comment: I just found out that it works for numbers, but my array is an array of objects, I forgot to mention that, see the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`resize` method pads with 0s in a flattened sense; the function pads with repeats.

To illustrate how `resize` "flattens" before padding:

```
In [108]: a = np.arange(12).reshape(1,4,3)
In [109]: a
Out[109]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]]])
In [110]: a1 = a.copy()
In [111]: a1.resize((2,4,4))
In [112]: a1
Out[112]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0]],

       [[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0]]])
```

If instead I make a target array of the right shape, and copy, I can maintain the original multidimensional block:

```
In [114]: res = np.zeros((2,4,4),a.dtype)
In [115]: res[:a.shape[0],:a.shape[1],:a.shape[2]]=a
In [116]: res
Out[116]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  0],
        [ 3,  4,  5,  0],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  0],
        [ 9, 10, 11,  0]],

       [[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0]]])
```

I wrote out the slices explicitly (for clarity).  Such a tuple could be created programmatically if needed.